# Python httplib2, AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, httplib2

I'm playing with the Python library [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/). The following is my code.

```
import urllib.parse
import httplib2

httplib2.debuglevel = 1

http = httplib2.Http()

url = "http://login.sina.com.cn/hd/signin.php"
body = {"act": "1",
        "entry": "vblog",
        "password": "P@$sW0rd",
        "reference": "http://vupload.you.video.sina.com.cn/u.php?m=1&cate=0",
        "reg_entry": "vblog",
        "remLoginName": "on",
        "username": "this_is_user_name",
        "x": "",
        "y": ""}

headers = {"Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
           "Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate",
           "Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5",
           "Connection", "keep-alive",
           "Content-Length", "181",
           "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Host", "login.sina.com.cn",
           "Keep-Alive", "115",
           "Referer", "http://login.sina.com.cn/hd/signin.php?entry=vblog&r=http%3A%2F%2Fvupload.you.video.sina.com.cn%2Fu.php%3Fm%3D1%26cate%3D0",
           "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16"}

response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', headers=headers, body=urllib.parse.urlencode(body))
```

When I execute it, I get the error:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\>python --version
Python 3.2

C:\>python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 32, in <module>
    response, content = http.request(url, 'POST', urllib.parse.urlencode(body), headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 961, in request
    headers = _normalize_headers(headers)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 184, in _normalize_headers
    return dict([ (key.lower(), NORMALIZE_SPACE.sub(value, ' ').strip())  for (key, value) in headers.items()])
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'

C:\>
```

I'm pretty new to Python and httplib2, anything wrong in my code?

Comment: I wish everybody would provide the full traceback of their errors -- it would save so much time!

Comment: Hi Sven, how to get the full traceback? I'm new to Python and not sure whether the trace I provided is the full traceback.

Comment: You *did* provide the full traceback, but most people don't.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`headers` should be a dictionary, not a set:

```
headers = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           ...}
```

Note the colon instead of the comma.

Comment: I've made the same mistake. Thanks @Sven