# Access Github API using Personal Access Token with Python urllib2

Tags: python, api, github, authorization, urllib2

I am accessing the Github API v3, it was working fine until I hit the rate limit, so I created a Personal Access Token from the Github settings page.  I am trying to use the token with urllib2 and the following code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request

url = "https://api.github.com/users/vhf/repos"
token = "my_personal_access_token"
headers = {'Authorization:': 'token %s' % token}
#headers = {}

request = Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urlopen(request)
print(response.read())
```

This code works ok if I uncomment the commented line (until I hit the rate limit of 60 requests per hour).  But when I run the code as is I get `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Almost works!  
After 'Authorization' you need a colon outside of the quotations see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512993/python-httplib2-attributeerror-set-object-has-no-attribute-items

Comment: @bklynjones There is a colon there, so headers is a dict and your link isn't relevant.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't know why this question was marked down.  Anyway, I found an answer:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request
url = "https://api.github.com/users/vhf/repos"
token = "my_personal_access_token"

request = Request(url)
request.add_header('Authorization', 'token %s' % token)
response = urlopen(request)
print(response.read())
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing from Node. This was the tip I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I realize this question is a few years old, but if anyone wants to auth with a personal access token while also using the `requests.get` and `requests.post` methods you also have the option of using the method below:

```
request.get(url, data=data, auth=('user','{personal access token}'))
```

This is just basic authentication [as documented in the requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/), which apparently you can pass personal access tokens to [according to the github api docs.](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication)

From the docs:

> Via OAuth Tokens Alternatively, **you can use personal access tokens or**
>   **OAuth tokens instead of your password.**
>
> `curl -u username:token https://api.github.com/user`
>
> This approach is
>   useful if your tools only support Basic Authentication but you want to
>   take advantage of OAuth access token security features.